# A Combinatorial proof

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ be any two positive integers. How to prove the following equation:

\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 ! \lambda_2 ! \left(\sum_{j=0}^{\min{(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}} \binom{\lambda_1}{j} \binom{\lambda_2}{j} \right) = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)!,
\end{align*}
where $\binom{n}{r}= \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.

I try to prove as follows. Suppose that $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2$. 
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 ! \lambda_2 ! \left( \binom{\lambda_1}{0} \binom{\lambda_2}{0} + \binom{\lambda_1}{1} \binom{\lambda_2}{1} + \ldots \binom{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1} \binom{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} \right) = \lambda_1 ! (\lambda_1 +1)(\lambda_1 +2) \cdots (\lambda_1 +\lambda_2).
\end{align*}
So, I want to prove 
\begin{align*}
\lambda_2 ! \left( \binom{\lambda_1}{0} \binom{\lambda_2}{0} + \binom{\lambda_1}{1} \binom{\lambda_2}{1} + \ldots \binom{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1} \binom{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} \right) = (\lambda_1 +1)(\lambda_1 +2) \cdots (\lambda_1 +\lambda_2).
\end{align*}
How to proceed further? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\lambda_1$ green balls and $\lambda_2$ red balls, each labeled by a distinct number.

$\frac{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)!}{\lambda_1!\lambda_2!} = \binom{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}$ is the number of ways you can choose a group of $\lambda_1$ balls (of any colors) from all $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ balls.

You can count this in another way. There are $\binom{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-j} \binom{\lambda_2}{j}=\binom{\lambda_1}{j} \binom{\lambda_2}{j}$ ways to choose $\lambda_1-j$ green balls and $j$ red balls, for a total of $\lambda_1$ balls. If we sum over all possible color configurations (that is, sum over all $0 \le j \le \min(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$), then we have counted the total number of ways to choose a group of $\lambda_1$ balls.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Check out Vandermonde identity if you are still stuck.